# Circular motion of a ball suspended from the rim of a rotating table

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics, rotational-kinematics, centripetal-force

Susppose there is a ball with radius $r$ suspended to the rim of a circular spinning table with radius $R$ by a string with length $l$ which makes an incline angle $\theta$ with the vertical axis.
If I want to calculate the centripetal force of the ball, is it equal to: 
 $M_{\rm Ball}  (R+l\sin \theta) \omega  $ ?

Comment: Yes exactly. Its correct if the angle is measured with vertical.

Comment: But my classmate says using equivalence principle, the ball can be treated as being put on the rim of the table, so the force is: mass $\times R \times$ angular velocity$^2$, so I am confused.

Comment: How is equivalence principle applied here?Shouldn't we calculate the total length from center ?

Comment: I will add $r\sin \theta$ to the length, as the centre of mass of theball is not at the end of the string

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[image]

This is a diagram of the given setup . Now let's try to define the coordinates of the centre of mass of the hanging particle as a function of time :- 
$$  r(t) = (R'\cos (\omega t), R'\sin(\omega t),-(l+r)\cos \theta ) $$

Differentiating this result twice would yield you the acceleration as a function of time

$$ a(t)= (-\omega^{2} R'\cos (\omega t), -\omega^{2} R'\sin(\omega t),0) $$

Now combine the components of the acceleration to give you the direction and magnitude of the acceleration of the centre of mass of the hanging object. Hope it helped !

Comment: what is wrong with the solution ? please inform